# How to receive list of directories or file from ftp server with int-ftp:outbound-gateway?

Tags: spring, ftp, spring-integration, outbound

I defined ftp adapter to connect to ftp server, but I see ftp server log and don't see request sent to ftp server. my adapter code is :

```
<bean id="ftpClientFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.DefaultFtpSessionFactory">
    <property name="host" value="127.0.0.1"/>
    <property name="port" value="21"/>
    <property name="username" value="banks_reader"/>
    <property name="password" value="123456"/>
    <property name="clientMode" value="2"/>
    <property name="fileType" value="2"/>

</bean>


<int:channel id="inbound1">
    <int:queue/>
</int:channel>
<int:channel id="outbound"/>
<int-ftp:outbound-gateway id="gateway1"
                          session-factory="ftpClientFactory"
                          request-channel="inbound1"
                          reply-channel="outbound"
                          reply-timeout="777"
                          auto-create-local-directory="false"
                          auto-startup="true"
                          filename-pattern="*"
                          remote-file-separator="/"
                          command="ls"
                          command-options="-1 -f"
                          expression="payload"
                          order="1"
                          mput-regex=".*">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="1000"/>
</int-ftp:outbound-gateway>
```

which shows:

```
DEBUG PollingConsumer:208 - Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false' in application log
```

**when change usename and password for test (fake pass and usename) Does not change anything and throw exception**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your config looks good, but you have missed an approach a bit.
`<int-ftp:outbound-gateway>` is an event-driven request/reply component and it can't do anything with FTP until there is no `message` in the `inbound1`.
Even if it is `<queue>`, the `<poller>` initiates its work only if there is no that `Received no Message during the poll`.

Since you use `expression="payload"`, your `requestMessage` must contain a `payload` with `remote dir` from your FTP user home.

So, just send such a message to the `inbound1` and let us know how it is!

**UPDATE**

To perform the `LS` command on the `<int-ftp:outbound-gateway>` periodically with the same `dir` as a `payload` you have to configure something like this:

```
<inbound-channel-adapter channel="inbound1" expresssion="'/'">
    <poller fixed-delay="10000"/>
</inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Having that (and your `<gateway>`) case there is no need to have that `inbound1` channel as a `<queue>`

Comment: Send message to  `inbound1` one more time. You haven't share the start of your flow, that's why I can't figure out which problem you have. You can't configure fake `<inbound-channel-adapter>` to start your flow periodically.

Comment: ,yes that's right ,  add the `int:gateway` and run `toFtpFlow.lsGetAndRmFiles("/");` in application start ,it's worked,but  execute only once , how to periodically statement to run command and get object list?

Comment: thanks @Artem for help me and update your answer, according to [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ftp.html) documentation, i need run ls,mv,... command in my ftp server, how to run `toFtpFlow.lsGetAndRmFiles("/");` statement and get Object list ?

Comment: You can do that as a consecutive set of `<int-ftp:outbound-gateway>` components: the first for `LS`, then `<splitter>` and one more `<int-ftp:outbound-gateway>` for `MV`

Comment: thanks @Artem , in first step i needed call periodically LS commad and run  
`<int-ftp:outbound-gateway>` flow to ls mv ... , how to run periodically first `<int-ftp:outbound-gateway>` to run ls command ?

Comment: The `<inbound-channel-adapter>` in my answer does that for your

Comment: yes and thanks for answer :) but i think `<inbound-channel-adapter>` not supported recursive directory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75689/discussion-between-alireza-ala-and-artem-bilan).

Comment: it's worked @Artem thanks :) 
i have a  mis-understand to your solution.sorry